# Spark join hangs

Tags: join, apache-spark

I have a table with n columns that I'll call A. In this table there are three columns that i'll need:

- vat  -> String
- tax  -> String
- card -> String

*vat* or *tax* can be null, but not at the same time. 
For every unique couple of *vat* and *tax* there is at least one *card*.

I need to alter this table, adding a column **count_card** in which I put a text based on the number of cards every unique combination of *tax* and *vat* has.

So I've done this:

```
val cardCount = A.groupBy("tax", "vat").count

val sqlCard = udf((count: Int) => {
  if (count > 1)
    "MULTI"
  else
    "MONO"
})

val B = cardCount.withColumn(
          "card_count", 
          sqlCard(cardCount.col("count"))
        ).drop("count")
```

In the table B I have three columns now:

- vat -> String
- tax -> String
- card_count -> Int

and every operation on this DataFrame is smooth.

Now, because I wanted to import the new column in **A** table, i performed the following join:

```
val result = A.join(B, 
       B.col("tax")<=>A.col("tax") and 
       B.col("vat")<=>A.col("vat")
     ).drop(B.col("tax"))
      .drop(B.col("vat"))
```

Expecting to have the original table A with the column *card_count*.

Problem is that the join hangs, getting all system resources blocking the pc.

Additional details:

- Table **A** has ~1.5M elements and is read from parquet file;
- Table **B** has ~1.3M elements.
- System is a 8 thread and 30GB of RAM

Let me know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I didn't found out which was the issue, so I changed approach

```
val cardCount = A.groupBy("tax", "vat").count

val cardCountSet = cardCount.filter(cardCount.col("count") > 1)
  .rdd.map(r => r(0) + " " + r(1)).collect().toSet

val udfCardCount = udf((tax: String, vat:String) => {
  if (cardCountSet.contains(tax + " " + vat))
    "MULTI"
  else
    "MONO"
})

val result = A.withColumn("card_count",
            udfCardCount(A.col("tax"), A.col("vat")))
```

If someone knows a better approach let me know it